# Is there a detailed balance solution for the Lindblad equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, decoherence

It is known that the Lindblad equation is a master equation.

Does there exist a general approach to a detailed balance condition/solution for this equation?

Please either kindly provide the solution or a reference in scientific literature.